# Рефакторинг кода Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, рефакторинг

подскажите пожалуйста, код рабочий но хороший ли он с точки зрения написании правильного кода? Можно ли его как нибудь отрефакторить ?

У `User` есть связь `branches`
У `Branch` есть связь `kassa_group`

```
$user = User::find(1);

$collection = collect();

foreach ($user->branches as $branch) {
    foreach ($branch->kassa_group as $kassa_group) {
        $collection->push($kassa_group);
    }
}

return $collection->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Для упрощения задачи вы можете использовать тип связи has-many-through:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function kassa_group()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(KassaGroup::class, Branch::class);
    }
}
```

тогда в контроллере достаточно будет вызвать:

```
$user = User::find(1);

return $user->kassa_group;
```

для получения идентичного результата

Comment: К сожалению получаю ошибку Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'branches.user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `kassa_groups`.*, `branches`.`user_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `kassa_groups` inner join `branches` on `branches`.`id` = `kassa_groups`.`branch_id` where `branches`.`user_id` = 1)'